# Exclude file extensions regular expression

Tags: regex, vbscript

I have a regular expression for a URL check written in VBScript.

```
regLinkEx.Pattern = "(^|[\s>='])((((http|ftp|https):\/\/)?([а-яёa-z\-_]{1,})(\.[а-яёa-z\-_]{2,})*(\.([^exe|EXE|xml|XML|dll|DLL|ini|INI|bat|BAT|dat|DAT|bin|BIN|mif|MIF|txt|TXT|]){2,}|рф)+)([\w\-\.,@?^=%&amp;:/~\+#]*[\w\-\@?^=%&amp;/~\+#])?)"
```

I exclude file extensions that I need, but I also want to match letters from a to z
this is the part where I want, and I'm trying to do like this...

```
(\.[a-z]*([^exe|EXE|xml|XML|dll|DLL|ini|INI|bat|BAT|dat|DAT|bin|BIN|mif|MIF|txt|TXT|]){2,}|рф)+)
```

...but it doesn't work.

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0):

In a Regular Expression, square brackets indicate a match for "any character within".  So, for example, the regular expression `[^exe|EXE|xml]{2,}` matches any two characters that aren't in  [exEXml].

If you are looking to exclude certain file extensions, use [negative lookahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html).  Since negative lookaheads are zero-length, you can string them together to create behavior like "X followed by none of the following: EXE, XML, DLL" (the regex for this would be `X(?!EXE)(?!XML)(?!DLL)`).

As a side note, VBScript fully supports negative lookahead, does not support negative look behind (a significantly more complex and intensive behavior).